# Is there any way to hide the juggernaut's location on a map?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3, there are times when someone gets a juggernaut delivered to them (by getting it as a kill streak reward). But when someone has it on, you can see their location as a red diamond with a dot in the middle. I haven't gotten a juggernaut in any standard game modes, but with the community mode **infected**, there are games where you are juggernauts fighting strikers (on the dome map, to be more specific). The problem is, you can see everyone that is a juggernaut, even if you're the enemy. And that comes with a great disadvantage, because you can't hide from enemies. So, is there any way to mask your location on the map, or is it going to stay like that?

Answer (score -2):

No there is no way to hide a score streak reward on MW3 as far as I know, unless there are any form radar jammers.

Comment: Wait I forgot unless there are anyform radar jammers

Comment: This is more of a comment...

Comment: [You can edit your own answers.](http://i.imgur.com/gyZ4MTW.png)

Comment: @Scriblenautical But did it not answer the question...

Comment: Not really. The OP asked "Can I do [something]" and you answered "Yes, and no." Yes, you answered the question, but it is poorly constructed and could do with some backup research

Comment: yeah, what Ben said.